How to validate file uploaded to JSON:API based on the associated field?
I have a custom entity called contact_upload.
The custom entity has an entity reference field called fid, referencing file entities.
I am uploading files to this entity using jsonapi (using the jsonapi/contact_upload/contact_upload/xxx/fid endpoint).
I want to validate these files as they get uploaded to ensure they are valid for the context of my custom entity.
I'm trying to use an event subscriber for the FileValidationEvent, which works, but I can't find any way to identify the file being uploaded as one that will be attached to my custom entity, so it performs the validation for any file uploaded to Drupal. Is there any context I can use to constrain the validation to just the files I'm interested in?
I thought maybe I could use a hacky approach and rely on the file directory to know what kind of file it is, but when the validation event triggers it's still a temporary file.

What exactly does “valid for the context of my custom entity” mean?

It has to be a csv file with specific headers.

Ok, as I understand this, the question is to understand, in a validator, whether the file was uploaded to that specific jsonapi endpoint. Do I have that right? I am just making sure.

Yes, either that it was uploaded to that specific endpoint or that it was attached to that specific entity type

I've switched from using a FileValidationEvent on the file upload to putting a constraint on the field itself, which seems to be working.

That's good. I tweaked the post title for better find-ability.

Yes, I think constraints are the way to go. That's what I'm using to impose restrictions on file uploads via JSON:API as well.
